# Cakephp 3 how to add beforeFind on table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am reading the documentation and there seems to be no example of how to use the beforeFind in Cakephp 3. I thought maybe I could do it like I did it in 2, but that did not work. Here are the two ways I did it.

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, array $options, $primary){
        $primary = (bool) $primary;
        if(!empty($options['pure'])) {
            $query->hydrate(false)
                ->join([
                    'table' => 'main_'.$this->store_id,
                    'alias' => 'c',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'c.id = Stores.MAIN_ID',
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Second way:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
        if(!isset($config['store_id'])) throw new Exception('You must provide a store id');
        $this->store_id = $config['store_id'];
        $this->entityClass('P1\Model\Entity\Store');
        $this->eventManager()->attach([$this,'addMain'],'beforeFind');
    }
    public function addMain(Event $event, Query $query, array $options, $primary){
        $primary = (bool) $primary;
        if(!empty($options['pure'])) {
            $query->hydrate(false)
                ->join([
                    'table' => 'main_'.$this->store_id,
                    'alias' => 'c',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'c.id = Stores.MAIN_ID',
                ]);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used 3.x, but in previous versions you'd still need to return what was passed in from/to `beforeFind()`

Answer (score -1):

You must use method applyOptions from class Query.

```
$this->Posts->find()->applyOptions(['pure'=>true])->all()
```